# "not a GROUP BY expression" on BULK COLLECT SELECT

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have developed an anonymous PL / SQL block that lists the total number of employees hired on each day of the week. And then insert the results into a table. To optimize the process and avoid repeated context changes between the PL / SQL Engine and the SQL engine I have used the BULK COLLECT AND FORALL utilities.

```
DECLARE 

    TYPE R_EMLEADOS_DIAS_SEMANA IS RECORD(
        totalEmpleados INTEGER,
        dayOfWeek VARCHAR2(10)
    );

    TYPE t_empleados IS TABLE OF R_EMLEADOS_DIAS_SEMANA;

    v_empleados t_empleados;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL , TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_empleados
    FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY');

    FORALL v_index IN 1 .. v_empleados.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        INSERT INTO EJERCICIOS (EJERCICIO, VALOR_1, VALOR_2)
        VALUES (2, v_empleados(v_index).totalEmpleados, v_empleados(v_index).totalEmpleados || ' EMPLEADOS DADOS DE ALTA EL ' || v_empleados(v_index).dayOfWeek);
    COMMIT WORK;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -24381 THEN
                FOR v_index IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT LOOP
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
                          SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (v_index).ERROR_INDEX
                           || ':'
                           || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (v_index).ERROR_CODE);
                END LOOP;
            ELSE
                RAISE;
            END IF;
END;
/
```

When I run this block I get the following compilation error:

```
ORA-00979: Is not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: en línea 31
ORA-06512: en línea 13
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

I do not understand why the query does not work. If I run it normally it works perfectly.

Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

The table used for the exercise:

```
CREATE TABLE EJERCICIOS (
  EJERCICIO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  VALOR_1   NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
  VALOR_2   VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: did u already try just saying ...GROUP BY HIRE_DATE

Comment: without the forall and insert , it compiles fine in the environment where i tried.There should be some issues with data at your end.

Answer (score 1):

Well in Oracle 11gR2, when i do the below, I see no issue. Check if you are doing the same:

```
create table EJERCICIOS(EJERCICIO number, VALOR_1 number, VALOR_2 varchar2(100));
```

Proc

```
DECLARE
   TYPE R_EMLEADOS_DIAS_SEMANA IS RECORD
   (
      totalEmpleados   INTEGER,
      dayOfWeek        VARCHAR2 (10)
   );

   TYPE t_empleados IS TABLE OF R_EMLEADOS_DIAS_SEMANA;

   v_empleados   t_empleados;
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT (*) AS TOTAL, TO_CHAR (HIRE_DATE, 'DAY') AS DAY_OF_WEEK
       BULK COLLECT INTO v_empleados
       FROM EMPLOYEE
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR (HIRE_DATE, 'DAY');

   FORALL v_index IN 1 .. v_empleados.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT INTO EJERCICIOS (EJERCICIO, VALOR_1, VALOR_2)
              VALUES (
                        2,
                        v_empleados (v_index).totalEmpleados,
                           v_empleados (v_index).totalEmpleados
                        || ' EMPLEADOS DADOS DE ALTA EL '
                        || v_empleados (v_index).dayOfWeek);

   COMMIT WORK;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      IF SQLCODE = -24381
      THEN
         FOR v_index IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
         LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
                  SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (v_index).ERROR_INDEX
               || ':'
               || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (v_index).ERROR_CODE);
         END LOOP;
      ELSE
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
```

Output:

```
  EJERCICIO VALOR_1                                                                                              VALOR_2
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         2 2                                                                                                    2 EMPLEADOS DADOS DE ALTA EL THURSDAY
         2 2                                                                                                    2 EMPLEADOS DADOS DE ALTA EL FRIDAY
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Code is exactly the same. Except that the value_1 column is of type Number. I'm using Oracle 12c R2

Comment: @SergioSánchezSánchez Can you post the DDL of the table then to simulate the issue and help you. Also it would also working incase i change the `valor_1` column to `Number`.

Comment: @SergioSánchezSánchez. its working with me. There is certainly something else you are doing. Even i edited my post for you.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I'll check it out in a bit.  I'll tell you later

Comment: I can not run your solution in my environment. It tells me that the GROUP BY expression is not valid. I have had to change the expression group by to "group by HIRE_DATE"